# Trying to find out why setting an object equal to another updates both objects

Tags: java

#### Example Code

```
public class test {
    
    public test(){
        runTest();
    }
    
    private void runTest(){

//method 1
        int[] A = {1,2,3,4};
        int[] B = new int[A.length];        
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            B[i] = A[i]+1;
        }
        for (int i: A){
            System.out.println(" A: " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("----------");

        for (int i: B){
            System.out.println(" B: " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("----------");



//method 2                
        int[] C = {1,2,3,4};
        int[] D = C;
        for (int i = 0; i <D.length; i++){
            D[i]++;
        }
        for (int i: C){
            System.out.println(" C: " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("----------");

        for (int i: D){
            System.out.println(" D: " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("----------");

        
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new test();
    }
}
```

---

#### Question

I was running into an issue in one of my `methods` and found the issue was creating the temporary `object` altered the original, which I did not want to happen.  I was just wondering why this occurs, I was under the impression that setting an `object` equal to another only points it to that current location/state, not any future updates.

In other words, wanted to know why I have do what I did with `int A` and `int B` instead of doing what I did with `int C` and `int D`.

To make it even simpler, what is the difference between the two methods above?  I'm going to take a stab at it and say the `JVM` calls the same `reference` when either `int C` or `int D` is called, as I didn't create a new object as I did with the `int A` `int B`.

Comment: Your stab is correct. If you don't create a new object, you will just have a copy of a reference to an existing object.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, was double checking as I think I've gotten away with it in the past hence the confusion.

Comment: If you step through the code in your debugger you can see how each variable changes and which objects are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that with A and B, `B` is a copy of the array and a completely separate object from `A`.  With C and D, `D` is another array reference that refers to the same object as `C`.  `D` continues to refer to not just the "that current location/state", but that same object, until it is reassigned or it goes out of scope.  Whatever you do to the object referred to by `D` will be visible through `C` as well, as it is the same object.